# Detect and Read Entire UTF-8 File using C++11?

Tags: c++, utf-8, fstream

I know of this traditional way,

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cerrno>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("file.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    if (in)
    {
        std::string contents;
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        contents.resize((size_t)in.tellg()); // Allocate buffer
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

        // Read the file
        in.read(&contents[0], contents.size());

        // ... do something ..

        // Close
        in.close();
    }
    else
        throw(errno);
}
```

In order to detect if its ANSI or UTF-8 file, do I need to read first three bytes to check if BOM matches, or, is there a better C++11 way using codecvt? How can I make this [codecvt](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_mode) way work for entire file?

Comment: `do I need to read first three bytes to check if BOM matches` Most UTF-8 files do not have a BOM.

Comment: Let's assume all my utf-8 are saved with BOM and some are ANSI.

Comment: You have linked to a reference page to `std::codecvt`, so its full specifications are available to you. You should be able to figure out whether or not its facilities will work for your use case, or you will have to determine this yourself. What is your specific question? The problem here is that if you ask three C++ developers "what is a better C++11 way to do X", you will get four different answers. This is something that you need to decide for yourself, based on your specific requirements.

Comment: If everyone was able to figure it out themselves, there would be no point of having this question & answer site. Like I said I want to read the entire file and I am not sure how std::codecvt method works. They use a `wchar_t` and I am not sure why.

Comment: Just some background on the difficulties when there is no BOM https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070417-00/?p=27223

Comment: If you know _a priori_ that your files are either ANSI or UTF-8 with BOM, then checking the first 3 bytes would be sufficient.

Comment: Note: A BOM is metadata, not part of the text itself, so it should not normally be passed to "do something".